# Django model: Query of query or filter of filter

Tags: python, django, django-models, model

I have 2 models, and on the function, I need to filter in 'x' the users which has the id's equal the id's received. And secondly, I need to filter in another query (let's say 'y'), the description from model Detail, which has the person_id equal to the id's already filtered in 'x'. It's like a filter of a filter, or a query of a query.

```
class Person(models.Model):
user = models.ForeingKey(Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Detail(models.Model):
person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
description = models.TextField()

def test(request, id_user):
x = Person.objects.filter(user_id = id_user)
```

I don't know how to do it. I'm new to Python and Django. It would be something like this:
`y = Detail.objects.filter(person_id = id_x).`
But of course, this isn't right.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Your query `y = Detail.objects.filter(person_id = id_x)` is correct!

Comment: What you aim to do with the description is not entirely clear to me...

Comment: It's not correct, because it doesn't work.

Comment: well what is not working? You have a `Retail` record in the database that points to a person with `id=4` and you filter on `person_id=4` then it should normally return that `Retail` record. of course if there are no records (for that person id), then it will return no records.

Comment: I always get 'id_x' not defined.

Comment: well because you never assigned a value to that variable... You can get the id with `x.id` or `x.pk`.

Comment: By trying this way, it returns that queryset has no attribute 'id' or 'pk'

Comment: you use `.get(..)` since that is a *single* `Person` you are retrieving.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def test(request, id_user):
    person = get_object_or_404(Person, user_id=id_user)
    details = Detail.objects.filter(person_id=person.pk)
    # …
```

Comment: Using get() returns 'Person' object is not iterable..

Comment: I just gave up trying to figure out a way like this. So instead, I created a ForeingKey in class Detail, for Users, just like on model Person. Now, I'm filtering both models by the User ID, instead of filter one model from the filter of the other.

Comment: @LK_223: well you should *not* enumerate, so no `for person in persons`, or `{% for person in persons %}` since... there is only one `Person`.